# How to calculate readabilty in R with the tm package

Tags: r, nlp, tm

Is there a pre-built function for this in the `tm` library, or one that plays nicely with it?

My current corpus is loaded into tm, something like as follows:

```
s1 <- "This is a long, informative document with real words and sentence structure:  introduction to teaching third-graders to read.  Vocabulary is key, as is a good book.  Excellent authors can be hard to find." 
s2 <- "This is a short jibberish lorem ipsum document.  Selling anything to strangers and get money!  Woody equal ask saw sir weeks aware decay. Entrance prospect removing we packages strictly is no smallest he. For hopes may chief get hours day rooms. Oh no turned behind polite piqued enough at. "
stuff <- rbind(s1,s2) 
d <- Corpus(VectorSource(stuff[,1]))
```

I tried using [koRpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835894/how-do-i-extract-contents-from-a-korpus-object-in-r), but it seems silly to retokenize in a different package than the one I'm already using. I also had problems vectorizing its return object in a way that would allow me to reincorporate the results into `tm`.  (Namely, due to errors, it would often return more or fewer readability scores than the number of documents in my collection.)

I understand I could do a naive calculation parsing vowels as syllables, but want a more thorough package that takes care of the edge cases already (address silent e's, etc.).

My readability scores of choice are Flesch-Kincaid or Fry.

What I had tried originally where d is my corpus of 100 documents:

```
f <- function(x) tokenize(x, format="obj", lang='en')
g <- function(x) flesch.kincaid(x)
x <- foreach(i=1:length(d), .combine='c',.errorhandling='remove') %do% g(f(d[[i]]))
```

Unfortunately, x returns less than 100 documents, so I can't associate successes with the correct document.  (This is partly my misunderstanding of 'foreach' versus 'lapply' in R, but I found the structure of a text object sufficiently difficult that I could not appropriately tokenize, apply flesch.kincaid, and successfully check errors in a reasonable sequence of  apply statements.)

**UPDATE**

Two other things I've tried, trying to apply the koRpus functions to the tm object...

1. Pass arguments into the tm_map object, using the default tokenizer:
   `tm_map(d,flesch.kincaid,force.lang="en",tagger=tokenize)`
2. Define a tokenizer, pass that in.

   ```
    f <- function(x) tokenize(x, format="obj", lang='en')
    tm_map(d,flesch.kincaid,force.lang="en",tagger=f)
   ```

Both of these returned:

```
   Error: Specified file cannot be found:
```

Then lists the full text of d[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835894/how-do-i-extract-contents-from-a-korpus-object-in-r)].  Seems to have found it?  What should I do to pass the function correctly?

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the error I get when I try to map koRpus functions directly with lapply:

```
> lapply(d,tokenize,lang="en")
Error: Unable to locate
 Introduction to teaching third-graders to read.  Vocabulary is key, as is a good book.  Excellent authors can be hard to find.
```

This looks like a strange error---I almost don't think it means it can't locate the text, but that it can't locate some blank error code (such as, 'tokenizer'), before dumping the located text.

**UPDATE 3**

Another problem with retagging using `koRpus` was that retagging (versus the tm tagger) was extremely slow and output its tokenization progress to stdout.  Anyway, I've tried the following:

```
f <- function(x) capture.output(tokenize(x, format="obj", lang='en'),file=NULL)
g <- function(x) flesch.kincaid(x)
x <- foreach(i=1:length(d), .combine='c',.errorhandling='pass') %do% g(f(d[[i]]))
y <- unlist(sapply(x,slot,"Flesch.Kincaid")["age",])
```

My intention here would be to rebind the `y` object above back to my `tm(d)` corpus as metadata, `meta(d, "F-KScore") <- y`.

Unfortunately, applied to my actual data set, I get the error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  cannot get a slot ("Flesch.Kincaid") from an object of type "character"
```

I think one element of my actual corpus must be an NA, or too long, something else prohibitive---and due to the nested functionalizing, I am having trouble tracking down exactly which it is.

So, currently, it looks like there is no pre-built function for reading scores that play nicely with the `tm` library.  Unless someone sees an easy error-catching solution I could sandwich into my function calls to deal with inability to tokenize some apparently erroneous, malformed documents?

Comment: Can't you use the `flesh.kincaid` from koRpus with `tm_map` from tm?

Comment: I can't seem to.  It says, "Error: No language specified!" for every variation of `tm_map(dd,flesch.kincaid)` I can think of, such as `tm_map(dd,flesch.kincaid, "en")`, etc.

Comment: So, I consulted another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827299/r-apply-function-with-multiple-parameters) about how to pass arguments into nested functions.  I tried this `tm_map(d,flesch.kincaid,force.lang="en",tagger=tokenize)` but get an error that it cannot find the "specified file", then outputs the contents of document 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because `koRpus` functions can't deal with `corpus` object. It is better to create a `kRp.tagged` object then apply all  `koRpus` features on it. Here I will show how I do this using `ovid` data of `tm` package.

I use `list.files` to get my list of source files. You just need to give the right path to your sources text files.

```
ll.files <- list.files(path = system.file("texts", "txt", 
                                    package = "tm"),
                 full.names=T)
```

Then I construct a list of `kRp.tagged` object using `tokenize` which is a the default tagger given with the `koRpus` package(It is recommanded to use `TreeTagger` but you need to install it)

```
ll.tagged <- lapply(ll.files, tokenize, lang="en") ## tm_map is just a wrapper of `lapply`
```

Once I have my list of "tagged" objects I can apply readability formula on it. Since `flesch.kincaid` is a wrapper of `readability`, I will apply directly the latter:

```
ll.readability <- lapply(ll.tagged,readability)          ## readability
ll.freqanalysis <- lapply(ll.tagged,kRp.freq.analysis)   ## Conduct a frequency analysis
ll.hyphen <- lapply(ll.tagged,hyphen)                    ## word hyphenation
```

etc,....all this produces a list of S4 object.  The `desc` slot gives an easy access to this list:

```
lapply(lapply(ll.readability ,slot,'desc'),              ## I apply desc to get a list
         '[',c('sentences','words','syllables'))[[1]]    ## I subset to get some indexes
[[1]]
[[1]]$sentences
[1] 10

[[1]]$words
[1] 90

[[1]]$syllables
all  s1  s2  s3  s4 
196  25  32  25   8
```

You can for example , use the slot `hyphen` to get a data frame with two colums, word (the hyphenated words) and syll (the number of syllables). here, using `lattice`, I bind all the data.frames, to plot a `dotplot` for each document.

```
library(lattice)
ll.words.syl <- lapply(ll.hyphen,slot,'hyphen')     ## get the list of data.frame
ll.words.syl <- lapply(seq_along(ll.words.syl),      ## add a  column to distinguish docs
       function(i)cbind(ll.words.syl[[i]],group=i))
dat.words.syl <- do.call(rbind,ll.words.syl)
dotplot(word~syll|group,dat.words.syl,
        scales=list(y=list(relation ='free')))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful answer and helpful, but if the format I have is not stored locally as the ovid text files are, I'm still not understanding how to do the tokenization and relate it back to tm objects.  I've used that library for other analyses, so I still need a way of keying koRpus readability scores back to those entities, even if I'm switching to koRpus entirely for this algo.

Comment: @Mittenchops thanks! ok no locally but where they are? what do you mean by getteing the socres  to tm.. if the score is by document it is easy to put it in your tm objects as a **meta** something like `meta(doc[i],'scoree') <- score`...

Comment: Thanks, @agstudy.  I added an update above.  The process that produces the corpus is a lot more complicated than that from the data source I'm getting it from, but I'll need to go to and from a format like that.  The issue preventing my earliest solution above has been that if there are blank string documents, the reading level  score just drops them, and I can't map out of, and back into, tm correctly.  `d` above is the object I'm starting with.

Comment: @Mittenchops I still not understanding why you can't save your d <- Corpus(VectorSource(stuff[,1])) in a file and then proceed like above..?

Comment: I will have to check if I know how to do that.  =) Do I lose my metadata that way?  I've been pulling from csv files so I haven't done direct IO with tm before.  It'd seem cleaner to if it's memory, just keep it there, rather than writing out only to read back again, right?

Comment: In therory yes...But you assume that the 2 packages have to work together in a coherent manner..maybe you want too much? that 'said you can save in a connection(stream) I ll detail this if I have more time..

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry the koRpus package doesn't interact with the tm package that smoothly yet. I've been thinking of ways to translate between the two object classes for months now but haven't yet come up with a really satisfying solution. If you have ideas for this, don't hesitate to contact me.

However, I'd like to refer you to the `summary()` method for readability objects produced by koRpus, which returns a condensed `data.frame` of relevant results. This is probably much easier to access than the alternative crawl through the rather complex S4 objects ;-) You might also try `summary(x, flat=TRUE)`.

@agstudy: Nice graph :-) To save some time, you should run `hyphen()` before `readability()`, so you can re-use the results via the "hyphen" argument. Or you can simply access the "hyphen" slot of `readability()` results afterwards. It will hyphenate automatically if needed, and keep the results. A manual call to hyphen should only be necessary if you need to change the output of `hyphen()` before next steps. I might add that 0.05-1 is *much* faster at this than its predecessors.

Comment: I haven't see your comment before! I guess you are the author of the `koRpus` package. +1!

Answer (score 2):

As of [qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/), qdap has a [number of functions](http://trinker.github.io/qdap/tdm.html) to be more compatible with the tm package.  Here is a way to approach your problem using the same `Corpus` you provide (note that the Fry was originally a graphical measure and qdap preserves this; also by way of your Corpus and the random sampling Fry suggested your sample Corpus is not large enough to calculate Fry's on):

```
library(qdap)
with(tm_corpus2df(d), flesch_kincaid(text, docs))

##   docs word.count sentence.count syllable.count FK_grd.lvl FK_read.ease
## 1   s1         33              1             54       16.6       34.904
## 2   s2         49              1             75       21.6       27.610

with(tm_corpus2df(d), fry(text, docs))

## To plot it
qheat(with(tm_corpus2df(d), flesch_kincaid(text, docs)), values=TRUE, high="red")
```

[image]