# Attaching meaningful names to texts with the koRpus package

Tags: r

I have a set of almost 3000 texts in a folder that I would like to analyse using the method explained in the answer here: 
[How to calculate readabilty in R with the tm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858267/how-to-calculate-readabilty-in-r-with-the-tm-package?lq=1). However, this will give me a list of 3000 texts, which I could only refer to by their index number. Is there a way to attach meaningful way to the tagged.text object? I would then calculate e.g. the mean sentence length by author, etc.

Comment: The question is not clear :are you looking to add some meta attribute to each corpus Or you just want to access list of corpus by names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to `setNames`?

```
setNames( list('file1','file2','file3'), c("foo", "bar", "baz") )
$foo
[1] "file1"

$bar
[1] "file2"

$baz
[1] "file3"
```